# I am looking for the name of this 80's Anime about a perturbed school boy who became a sorcerer and lives inside a painting

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm looking for the name of this Anime from the 80's. I'm sorry I can't give you more details, but I hardly remember it. I just remember it was very dark and scary, but I was just 8 years old(so maybe that's not very objective).

It is about a very very perturbed School Boy who became a kind of wizard, specifically a  sorcerer. In one scene, for example, he dropped his bag and a dead frog, a poison, a book and some other creepy thing came out of it. He was always scared and stressed.

When the support character ( I can't remember if it was girl or a boy) tries to help him, they end up in a very creepy mansion. In that house, the haven of the boy was a magic painting of a landscape which acted like a portal to other "dimension" where he had a house. He kind of lives inside the painting.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The bit about a portal painting reminds me of Shamanic Princess, but not the other details.

Comment: When you say "anime", do you just mean 'animated film/tv' or was it specifically Japanese?

Comment: It was japanese. Very old. around 1986. The boy was getting insane with all the power. When the support character tries to help him, it follows him to the house, then saw the painting and inside of it was the boy running to a little house. Can't remember how they got in.

Comment: No, it is not Lew Delport. But thanks.